# MSB6001 Invalid command line switch for "link.exe"

Tags: c++, function, winapi, dll

I import functions from my dll everything worked fine until I wanted to use a def file. Now I get this error: `MSB6001 Invalid command line switch for "link.exe". System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.`

I used to get `LNK1104` error but after I used colons in my `Additional Dependencies` I get the error above.

- <kbd>Post-Build Events</kbd> > <kbd>Command Line</kbd> here I got the following: `xcopy /y /d "..\..\HookLibrary\$(IntDir)HookLibrary.dll" "$(OutDir)"`
- <kbd>Additional depencies</kbd>: `HookLibrary.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`
- <kbd>Linker</kbd> > <kbd>Command Line</kbd> (while configuration = debug): `/OUT:"C:\Users\yigit\Desktop\Hook\HookClient\x64\Debug\HookClient.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\yigit\Desktop\Hook\HookClient\x64\Debug\HookClient.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "HookLibrary.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEF:"HookDef.def" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\yigit\Desktop\Hook\HookClient\x64\Debug\HookClient.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\HookClient.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"x64\Debug\HookClient.iobj" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"x64\Debug\HookClient.ilk" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"..\..\HookLibrary\x64\Debug\" /TLBID:1`
- <kbd>Linker</kbd> > <kbd>Command Line</kbd> (while configuration = release): `/OUT:"C:\Users\yigit\Desktop\Hook\HookClient\x64\Release\HookClient.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\yigit\Desktop\Hook\HookClient\x64\Release\HookClient.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "HookLibrary.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEF:"HookDef.def" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\Users\yigit\Desktop\Hook\HookClient\x64\Release\HookClient.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\HookClient.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"x64\Release\HookClient.iobj" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"x64\Release\HookClient.ilk" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"..\..\HookLibrary\x64\Release\" /TLBID:1`

My additional dependencies are correct.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you [edit] your question to include the commands, options and flags you use when building. How do you build? How do you invoke the linker? And please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into the question (as text!) Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Sure, I'm gonna do it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use semicolons `;` to separate files in `Additional Dependencies` or better select `<Edit...>` and fill dependecies line by line.

[image]

[image]

Linker command line can be verified under `Linker`->`Command Line`.

Comment: Everything seems to be right except for the Command Line you are reffering to. I don't have anything written there. What command do I have to put there?

Comment: I think I have to add something there because the error says: Length cannot be less than zero. If this also doesn't work I'm deleting Visual Studio and install an older version.

Comment: Please paste `Command Line`->`All Options` in your question - it seems that something is wrong there. It is automatically generated from options selected in other pages (you can't edit it). `Command Line`->`Additional Options` in most cases is empty.

Comment: And show your additional dependencies eg. copy it into question.

Comment: I pasted my additional dependenties. I have literally nothing inside my Additional Options

Comment: Show `Command Line`->`All Options`. This is command send to linker, maybe something is wrong in it.

Comment: <different options>    This what's in there.

Comment: Change `Configuration` to `Debug` or `Release` (not `All Configurations`) and change `Platform` to something other than `All Platforms`.

Comment: Ok, I posted it. I set Configuration to Debug

Comment: I'm also adding Release

Comment: You have empty quoted argument after dependencies (two double quotes) `"odbccp32.lib" "" /DEF:"HookDef.def"`. Unfortunatelly I don't know from which option it is generated.

Comment: What do you think I should do now?

Comment: Clear `Additional Dependencies` (just leave `%(AdditionalDependencies)`) and clear `Module Definition File` and check if unwanted argument `""` will disappear.

Comment: I did what you said. The two double quotes "" are now gone.

Comment: Maybe I added the .def file the wrong way?

Comment: Or maybe my problem is with the dll? I don't think that's the case because without adding the .def file it works fine.

Comment: All of this started because I wanted to use the SetWindowsHookEx, the documentation said that I had to pass the name of the function as it is written in the def file

Comment: Try to compile, if linker reports undefined references, you at least go past command line. Next add `Additional Dependencies`, check command line, try to compile. If linker goes past command line parsing, try to fill `Module Definition File`, check command line, try to compile.

Comment: It works fine when I delete Module Definition File. But then it imports the functions without the .def file

Comment: I'm gonna try what you are saying

Comment: Weird when I remove the double quotes from additional dependencies it works fine. Now I need to insert the .def file

Comment: I think I got 1 step closer to the solution. Now when I want to build (with def file) I get this error: LNK1104 cannot open file 'HookDef.def'

Comment: I updated my question. Linker > Command Line (while configuration = release) the double quotes are removed now

Comment: Is `'HookDef.def` in folder where `*.vcxproj` is located? If not build **relative** or **absolute** path.

Comment: Yes they are in at the same place. HookDef.def is in the same place as HookLibrary.vcxproj

Comment: _To specify a .def file from within the development environment, you should add it to the project along with other files and then specify the file to the /DEF option._ [/DEF (Specify Module-Definition File)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/def-specify-module-definition-file?view=msvc-170)

Comment: I can finally build it succesfully. I think one last step because when I compile my program it says: unable to start program/HookClient.exe is not a valid win32 program.

Comment: I think I can solve this problem. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.